# PostgreSQL bytea vs smallint[]

Tags: postgresql, datatypes, blob, bytea

I'm looking to import large (100Mb -- 1 GB) multi-channel time-series data into a PostgreSQL database. The data comes from [EDF format](http://www.edfplus.info/specs/edf.html) files that chunks the data into "records" or "epochs" of typically a few seconds each. Each epoch's record holds the signals for each channel of data as sequential arrays of short integers.

I'm mandated to store the files within the database, in the worst case as BLOBs. Given that, I'd like to investigate options that would allow me to do something more with the data within the database, such as facilitating queries based upon the signal data.

My initial plan is to store the data as one row per epoch record. What I'm trying to weigh up is whether to store the actual signal data as bytea or smallint[] (or even smallint[][]) types. Could anyone recommend one over the other? I'm interested in storage and access costs. Usage is likely to be insert once, read occasionally, update never. If one were more easily wrapped up as a custom type such that I could add functions for analysing of comparing records then so much the better.

No doubt I'm low on detail, so feel free to add comments on what you'd like me to clarify.

Comment: This might be one of the few sensible uses for array use in the authorative data model, since you save a *lot* of disk space by avoiding the 24 to 28-byte row overhead. Arrays are also compressed and stored out-of-line if long enough.

Comment: beldaz, the way in which you should store the data has much to do with how you plan to access it, and how often.  If the data is rarely queried, and you always want to just pull the data on a per-record basis, then I think one row per record in an array makes good sense.  However, if you wish to do any querying that is slightly more in-depth, such as pulling up all records for a given patient_id, for example, then perhaps we can suggest a slight improvement to the storage structure. Any ideas about your query patterns?

Comment: @Chris Thanks. I've left out the metadata component as that's very small and can reside in a separate relation. Query patterns are TBD, but I may want to compared two different files recorded at the same time, and pull out signals from simultaneous epochs.

Comment: @CraigRinger I didn't see much evidence of array compression. Does this need to be enabled in some way?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the absence of any answers I've explored the issue further myself.

It looks like [user-defined functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/xfunc-c.html) can handle all base types, [including](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/xfunc-c.html#XFUNC-C-TYPE-TABLE) `bytea` and `smallint[]`, so this doesn't affect the choice of representation much.

I tried out several different representations on a PostgreSQL 9.4 server running locally on a Windows 7 laptop with a vanilla configuration. The relations to store that actual signal data were as follows.

**Large Object for entire file**

```
CREATE TABLE BlobFile (
    eeg_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    eeg_oid OID NOT NULL
);
```

**SMALLINT array per channel**

```
CREATE TABLE EpochChannelArray (
    eeg_id INT NOT NULL,
    epoch INT NOT NULL,
    channel INT,
    signal SMALLINT[] NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (eeg_id, epoch, channel)
);
```

**BYTEA per channel in each epoch**

```
CREATE TABLE EpochChannelBytea (
    eeg_id INT NOT NULL,
    epoch INT NOT NULL,
    channel INT,
    signal BYTEA NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (eeg_id, epoch, channel)
);
```

**SMALLINT 2D array per epoch**

```
CREATE TABLE EpochArray (
    eeg_id INT NOT NULL,
    epoch INT NOT NULL,
    signals SMALLINT[][] NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (eeg_id, epoch)
);
```

**BYTEA array per epoch**

```
CREATE TABLE EpochBytea (
    eeg_id INT NOT NULL,
    epoch INT NOT NULL,
    signals BYTEA NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (eeg_id, epoch)
);
```

I then imported a selection of EDF files into each of these relations via Java JDBC and compared the growth in database size after each upload.

The files were:

- File A: 2706 epochs of 16 channels, each channel 1024 samples (16385
  samples per epoch), 85 MB
- File B: 11897 epochs of 18 channels, each channel 1024 samples (18432 samples per epoch), 418 MB
- File C: 11746 epochs of 20 channels, each channel 64 to 1024 samples (17088 samples per epoch), 382 MB

In terms of storage cost, here's the size occupied in MB for each case:
[image: Storage cost in MB]

Relative to the original file size, Large Objects were about 30-35% larger. By contrast, storing each epoch as either a BYTEA or SMALLINT[][] was less than 10% larger. Storing each channel as a separate tuple give a 40% increase, as either BYTEA or SMALLINT[], so not much worse than storing as a large object.

One thing I hadn't initially appreciated is that "Multidimensional arrays must have matching extents for each dimension" [in PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/arrays.html). This means that the `SMALLINT[][]` representation only works when all channels in an epoch have the same number of samples. Hence File C fails to work with the `EpochArray` relation.

In terms as access costs, I haven't played around with this, but at least in terms of inserting the data initially the fastest representation was `EpochBytea` and `BlobFile`, with `EpochChannelArray` the slowest, taking about 3 times as long as the first two.

Comment: From an academic perspective, I find your results very interesting, but from a practical standpoint, is the storage size of great concern? Perhaps in your use case you have very many records, and so storage is an issue you face?  However, in this storage format, any lookup other than by epoch (or channel, when in the appropriate schema) would require reading a portion of every record.  Is this OK for your application?

Comment: Practically yes, it certainly is important for me, as I'm expecting to deal with several TB of raw files. As it turns out the current in overhead is lower than I expected, but if it had been 300% for a particular representation I'd certainly avoid it. As for querying I wouldn't expect to access by anything other than epoch and channel.